# show data from jTable in jFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jbutton

I have jFrame2 which contains jTable with 4 columns (the jTable taking data from table in database which contain 20 columns)
Also I have jFrame1 which I have used it to fill database.
What I want to do that when I select row in jTable and click jButton, it must open jframe1 showing all data for that row.
i will clear what i want in points

*i want open jframe1 from jframe2 via jbutton(this task is done and this is the code)

```
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource()==jButton2){
       jframe2 regFace =new jframe2();
      regFace.setVisible(true);
   }}
```

*once jframe1 opened by jbutton in jframe2 it must show in it fields all data of selected row in jframe2>>this point mean

........-sql query executed once jfram1 opened by Jbutton in jframe2

.........-showing data in jtextfield taking from database by query i mentioned in line above (this task is done and this is the code but not completed)

```
try {
   dbconnect = new myDbConnection();
        ResultSet resultSet =null;
        resultSet = dbconnect.excuteQuery("SELECT id, area,location, status1 FROM pledges where id='17'");

       while (resultSet.next()){
              id.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
                area.setText(resultSet.getString(2));
                location.setText(resultSet.getString(3));
                status.setText(resultSet.getString(4));
                //         i = Long.parseLong(rs1.getString(1));
            }
```

*in brief i want understand jframe1 that please if you opened by jframe2 execute a query and fill text fields by that query
*this is picture would clear better
[here](http://www.zshare.net/image/889479437e2a5c94/)

Comment: You should NOT show another frame. Generally appplications should only have a single JFrame. In this case your detail window should be a JDialog.

Comment: why..i'm using jFrame becuse i want all features of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before i put the answer i would thank @wolfcastle such a nice person.He almost answer the question and i'm just modify it to adapt it with sql query and database.
this is the code for jfrme2

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if(e.getSource()==jButton2){
         int viewRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int modelRow = jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
Object oc=  jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
String vv=oc.toString();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
jframe1 regFace =new jframe1();
        try {
            regFace.setSelectedRow(vv);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(showp1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
regFace.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

and the the code for jframe1

```
public void setSelectedRow(String row ) throws SQLException {
dbconnect = new myDbConnection();
        ResultSet resultSet =null;
        System.out.print(row);
        resultSet = dbconnect.excuteQuery("SELECT id, area,location, status1 ,date1,insname,oname,bname,street,junction,INSPSITION,recname1 FROM pledges where id='"+row+"'");
while (resultSet.next()){
              id.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
                area.setText(resultSet.getString(2));
                location.setText(resultSet.getString(3));
                status.setText(resultSet.getString(4));
                date.setText(resultSet.getString(5));
                insname.setText(resultSet.getString(6));
                oname.setText(resultSet.getString(7));
                bname.setText(resultSet.getString(8));
                street.setText(resultSet.getString(9));
                junction.setText(resultSet.getString(10));
                insposition.setText(resultSet.getString(11));
                recname.setText(resultSet.getString(12));
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the part you are having trouble with is how to get the selected data from the table into the fields in jframe1.

A lot of this depends on the `TableModel` that is used in your `JTable`. Assuming you just used a `DefaultTableModel`, you can get the selected row data like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int viewRow = myJTable.getSelectedRow();
    int modelRow = myJTable.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) myJTable.getModel();

    // You will get a compiler warning on the following line, but there's not much you can do about it beside suppress it
    Vector<Object> rowVector = (Vector<Object>) model.getDataVector().get(modelRow);

    jframe2 regFace =new jframe2();
    regFace.setSelectedRow(rowVector);
    regFace.setVisible(true);       
}
```

And you would have the following method in your jframe2 class:

```
public void setSelectedRow(Vector<Object> row ) {
    id.setText(row.get(0).toString());
    area.setText(row.get(1).toString());
    location.setText(row.get(2).toString());
    status.setText(row.get(3).toString());
    // continue for all columns
}
```

Comment: in jFrame2 i've this code.......................... public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {if(e.getSource()==jButton2){
           jframe2 regFace =new jframe2();
   regFace.setVisible(true);}}........................... and i want data to be sent to jframe1 when i press on jButton. not:data must only be showed in text feilds of jframe1 if it was came from jframe2.

Comment: @m.basleem I'm still not clear on what you are having problems with. If you can edit your question and include a [SSCCE](http://www.pscode.org/sscce.html), that would help.

Comment: @wolfcastle i've clarified more details in my question. i hope its clear now..thanks for your care

Comment: @m.basleem Okay, I think I understand your question now. You want to know how to get the data from the JTable that the user has selected, and pass that to jframe1 to populate the various text fields. I'll respond shortly.

Comment: @m.basleem I've updated my answer. Hopefully this is more of what you were looking for.

Comment: @wolfcastle thank so much for your solution..it almost perfect..but there is a Little problem ..when i put sql query ,it give me error message..this my try...................................................public void setSelectedRow(Vector<Object> row ) throws SQLException {dbconnect = new myDbConnection();ResultSet resultSet =null;resultSet = dbconnect.excuteQuery("SELECT id, area,location FROM pledges where id='"+row.get(0).toString()+"'");
    while (resultSet.next()){id.setText(resultSet.getString(1));area.setText(resultSet.getString(2));location.setText(resultSet.getString(3));}}

Comment: @wolfcastle thank u so mutch for your care.iwould like to tell u that i've modify your solution and make it work with query and database..thank u again..Mohammed Basleem